# JavaScript Form Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to check if a form field has been left empty by the following code:

```
<script>

   function validateForm()
   {
       var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
       if (x==null || x=="")
         {
            alert(" Name Required* ");
            return false;
         }
    }

</script>

<form action="register2.php" method="POST" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
<input type="text" name="name"/>
</form>
```

But it only check input box, how can I check select box, radio button and check box ?

Comment: What is an "empty" checkbox? Surely unchecked is a valid state to submit for most purposes? Anyway, a hint: just as you already get a text input's text with the `.value` property, you can get a checkbox input's state with the `.checked` property.

Comment: The form doesn't have any radio buttons or checkboxes, how can you check them?

Comment: Maybe use the jquery-validate plugin? http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery form validation](https://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://jqueryvalidation.org/&ei=d5VrUu7XKojY4wS3p4GoDw&usg=AFQjCNGgspBxXlz7s7nbbkPHNbkz8jsNvg&bvm=bv.55123115,d.Yms&cad=rja) it has all things you need to validate

use this simple example 
http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use like this way.

```
    <script>
          function validateForm(frm)
          {

             if (frm.name.value == "")
             {
                 alert(" Name Required* ");
                 return false;
             }
            if(frm.country.value == 'select')
            {
                 alert(" Please select country ");
                 return false;
            }
         }
    </script>

             <form action="register2.php" method="POST" id="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm(this)" >
               <input type="text" name="name"/>
             <select name="country">
                  <option value="select">(Please select a country)</option>
                  <option value="pk">Pakistan</option>
                  <option value="chn">China</option>
             </select>
             </form>
```

Comment: I want to check Select menu must get a value that user cant send an empty value .

Comment: @bindiya Patoliya nnnnn kh rha h frm.name.value ko null se kyu check kiya.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dude, Use Validate Plugin for Validation

Example:
    $(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
 // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
 name: "required",
 // compound rule
 email: {
  required: true,
email: true
 }
   }
},
messages: {
 name: "Please specify your name",
  email: {
required: "We need your email address to contact you",
email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
}
```

} });
[Validate Plugin Document](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)